# crm2011 relationship with opportuntiy subgrid

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I create custom entity "Opp Product". In Opportunity entity, I create 1:N relationship with "Opp Product". And I try to add "opp product" new records clicking "Add New Opp Product" ribbon to the "Opportunity" subgrid, the record can create successfully.

But I try to add clicking "Add Existing Opp Product" ribbon to the Opportunity subgrid, I got this error. Anyone see it before?Any ideas please?

![image]

Comment: Have you checked this http://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/f/117/p/65550/119321.aspx#119321

Answer (score 1):

It says that your Existing Opp Product already linked to another Opportunity.

When you have 1:N relation you can link many Opp Products to a Opportunity.

In this case you're trying to link the same Opp Product to several Opportunities.
To do so you need N:N relation.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the existing Opp Product form and modify the Opportunity lookup to point to the opportunity that you desire.

The "Add Existing" option will only work if the Opp Product has not been associated with an opportunity yet.